# how to get Image.getPlanes() information for an image available in drawable folder?

Tags: android, image, tensorflow

I have an image(.jpg) available in my drawable folder. I need the Image.getPlanes() information of it for my image classification project. So how do we read that image and get the getPlanes information out of it?

Existing Code:

```
private byte[][] yuvBytes;
final Plane[] planes = **image**.getPlanes(); // How to create this image object?
fillBytes(planes, yuvBytes);

/* */
protected void fillBytes(final Plane[] planes, final byte[][] yuvBytes) {
  for (int i = 0; i < planes.length; ++i) {
     final ByteBuffer buffer = planes[i].getBuffer();
     if (yuvBytes[i] == null) {
       yuvBytes[i] = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
     }
     buffer.get(yuvBytes[i]);
   }
}
```

Need an Image object, that reads the image present in the Drawable folder.

Comment: and what do you want to do with the returned `Plane[]`?

Comment: I need the Plane[] information to the get the buffer data for the yuv planes, later convert it to convertYUV420ToARGB8888 to get the rgbBytes of that image. Which is used to Classify the image. This is all for a machine learning computer vision problem statement I am working on.

Comment: `rgbBytes`? the same array returned from `Bitmap#getPixels`?

Comment: yes, probably the same. I have updated the question, adding few more details regarding the problem statement, please have a look at it.